X-Cube STL in STM32H745ZI using IAR CRC area is not flashing while debug
I'm working on POST using X-cube STL in stm32h745zit3 using IAR 9.30.1 version, while flashing the code into target STM32 board it showing error in Debug log
post build command everything is fine, on build it's showing CRC area injected successfully, but while flashing it causing problem.
Debug Log : warnings it showing....
Flash Download warning 4096 out of 4098 bytes from data record CODE : [0x080FF000 - 0x080FFFFFF] will not be flashed.
Basically IAR not injecting CRC in to my target,
It worked perfectly fine in Nucleo-STM32H745ZI, but when I'm using custom board but code size will be more STM32H745ZIT3
--Update 1
I'm using STM32H7 for the POST which is not working in custom board any one have integrated this x-cube STL in their personal custom board
--Update 2
Getting this error appear in debug log ELF/DWARF Error: Unknown" and "Failed to load debugee
I have tried using IAR
